# colored images being converted to [1,1,1] for every pixel

Tags: image, tensorflow, matplotlib, colors, generator

I'm using a generator to make images. I tried printing out a generator image before training and it seems to output random values for RGB as expected. However the function I use to save show each step in the training says "Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."

If needed I can include the full code but it's really long. So for now here is the function that shows the images after each epoch.

```
def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_input):
  predictions = model(test_input, training=False)

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))

  for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
      print(predictions)
      plt.subplot(4, 4, i+1)
      plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, :] * 127.5 + 127.5)
      plt.axis('off')

  plt.show()
```

This is what it prints. Obviously that's only part of it of course.

```
[[[[-0.08561043 -0.16898969 -0.04297004]
   [-0.27353853 -0.11766727 -0.05380717]
   [-0.0349301   0.01892653 -0.02630406]
   ...
```

However, the images that show up in the plot have [1,1,1] for every pixel. I have no clue what's going on here.

Comment: if your array is of shape 3 and of type float, imshow assumes it to be RGB values between 0 and 1. However, you values exceed 1 by far, so they are truncated at 1. You should try to change the array type to integer, e.g. by adding ().astype(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array contains floats, you should normalize the values to the interval [0–1], and not 0–255.

You can try:

```
img = predictions[i, :, :, :]
img = (imp-np.min(img))/np.ptp(img)
plt.imshow(img)
```